# jquery unobtrusive validation attributes reference?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Where i can find the reference for **Unobtrusive jquery validation attributes** like

`data-val-length` , `data-val-required` etc..I want the full list of these attributes. Is

there any single place where i can find this?

Comment: Maybe this article will help: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The closest thing I've found is in the article [Some things I’ve learned about jQuery unobtrusive validation](https://web.archive.org/web/20130919030425/http://denverdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/some-things-ive-learned-about-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/). The article has better formatting and more info, but I've copied the good parts here in case it disappears.

- `data-val="true"`: enable unobtrusive validation on this element (should be on every input element you want to validate)
- `data-val-required="ErrMsg"`: makes the input required, and shows the ErrMsg
- `data-val-length="ErrMsg"`, `data-val-length-min="5"`, `data-val-length-max="15"`: sets required string length and associated error message.
- `data-val-number="ErrMsg"`: makes a field required to be a number.
- `data-val-date="ErrMsg"`: requires a field to be a date (I do not recommend this, as it accepts too much – I prefer to use regex).
- `data-val-equalto="ErrMsg"`, `data-val-equalto-other="Fld"`: requires one field to match the other (such as password confirm.  Fld is a jQuery selector
- `data-val-regex="ErrMsg"`, `data-val-regex-pattern="^regex$"`: Requires the field to match the regex pattern.
- `data-val-email="ErrMsg"`: requires a field to be a email (I do not recommend this, as it accepts too much – I prefer to use regex).
- `data-val-url="ErrMsg"`: requires a field to be a url (I do not recommend this, as it accepts too much – I prefer to use regex).

---

**Update:**

For displaying the validation message, add a container for each control you want to validate.

```
<div class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="controlName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></div>
```

Note that `data-valmsg-for` is the control's **name**, not id.

Comment: Here is the content from the link: https://web.archive.org/web/20130919030425/http://denverdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/some-things-ive-learned-about-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/

Comment: Can add to this `data-val-range="errorMessage"`, `data-val-range-min="0"` and `data-val-max="100"`

Answer (score 0):

It's Working code. I,m already used at this time.

```
var NoOfEMI = $('#venderForm [data-valmsg-for="NoOfEMI"]').empty();

NoOfEMI.html("Number of the EMI is required");
```